# Scene went black after pressing Ctrl + H

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, scene

[image: Minecraft Scene]

I was just working on my minecraft scene and I accidentally pressed ctrl+h and it went all black, does anyone know how to fix?

Comment: Ctrl+H makes the object not renderable, press Alt+Ctrl+H do enable renderability again (or press on the eye and camera icons on the outlilner)

Comment: @cegaton maybe this should better be an answer not an comment? :)

Comment: @J.Doe feel free to write one.